# How do I return only the value as a string and not a collection?

Tags: laravel

This eloquent collection provides this result:

```
$id = Model::where('s_id', $s_id)->pluck('l_id');
```

```
print_r($id)
```

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => 31242682774
        )

)
```

How do I return only the "31242682774" value as a string and not a collection?

**EDIT ANSWER:**

All I had to do is:

```
$id = Model::where('s_id', $s_id)->pluck('l_id')->first();
```

Any better options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on when in the process you wanna do it. On the query execution or after. The most common approach would probably be.

```
$id = Model::where('s_id', $s_id)->first()->l_id;
```

This will get the string after the query is executed, meaning the query builder will fetch all columns in the row. In general in `Laravel` you don't often work with strings, instead you get data from your model. `Model::where('s_id', $s_id)->first()` will return your model and select the `l_id` property on it.

The approach you chosen is the database way, you only select the l_id and return it as a collection and select the first item from there. This is thou a very performance efficient way of doing it since the database does all the work and is very quick at it.

```
$id = Model::where('s_id', $s_id)->pluck('l_id')->first();
```

The reason why it is a collection, it is mainly made for selecting multiple id's, so if you query returned multiple rows multiple ids would be returned. Here you can see an example of pluck in conditional queries, where it is most often used.

```
$teamIds = Team::where('type', 'admin')->pluck('id');

$adminUsers = User::where('team_id', $teamIds)->get();
```

Your solution is perfect for what you need, just trying to bring clarity on why and a example of how it is often used.

Answer (score 4):

If you only need a single value, not multiple values, `pluck` isn't what you want. There is a method called `value` on Query Builder that returns a single value:

```
Model::where('s_id', $s_id)->value('l_id');
```

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Query Builder - Retrieving Results - Retrieving A Single Row / Column From A Table](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#retrieving-results) `value`